# Simplifying a Karnaugh Map

Tags: circuit, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

In this image it says the Output should be A' + B, but to me, it seems like it should be A' + AB.  If I'm wrong, could someone explain to me how A' + B is the correct answer?  The reason I ask this is because in the second group of ones, you get ABC + ABC'.  Since A and B areboth common in the last two groups, shouldn't they both be included?  Thanks in advance.

[Karnaugh Map Simplification Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9p8n.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key bit you are missing is that `A' + B` *is equal to* `A' + AB`

Because of the Distributive Property of boolean algebra we can rewrite

```
A' + AB
```

as the product

```
(A' + A)(A' + B)
```

and since the first term is the same as just saying `1`, we are left with only our second term.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that.  I went back and read through everything, and even though I read through the different properties, I just didn't catch this.  Thank you so much for clearing that up and helping me look for this type of situation in the future.  So I was on the right track except that I just didn't understand why the second A was redundant, right?